# Jquery apply one source image to another

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anythingslider

I've got a larger slider image and a smaller "thumbnail" image. I have this code so far:

```
 $j(".slider-img").each( function(){
  var slideSource = $j(this).attr("src");
   $j(".slider-thumb").each(function() {
    $j(this).attr("src", slideSource); 
   });
 });
```

But its giving me the image from the first slide for all of the thumbnails. So I want to take the source from each .slider-img and apply it to each .slider-thumb. Ideas?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are the two associated in any way? Only the last .slider-img is going to have any effect in this code setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the `.slider-img` that corresponds to a `.slider-thumb` is in the same position in the document, relative to the others with that class, you can use this:

```
var thumbs = $j('.slider-thumb');
$j('.slider-img').each(function(i) { // i is the position in the set
    thumbs.eq(i).attr('src', this.src); // set the src attribute of the element with position i in the thumbs set to the src of this element
});
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason Slide one has thumbnail 5, slide 2 has thumbnail 1, and so on. For some reason the thumbnails are jumping ahead of their slides! Very odd, but its a start, thank you! Any ideas on why its doing that?

Comment: @Tom Probably the images are not in the same order in the source code. If you can show your HTML, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to find the corresponding thumb when you're in your image.
It can be a "rel" attribute on your parent image (or on the thumb), it's not very official-w3c-clean but it's used :-)

You can as well try to find the thumb by "walking in the DOM with the travsering functions http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ it could make something like that:

```
 $j(".slider-img").each( function(){
   var slideSource = $j(this).attr("src");
   var thethumb = $j(".slider-thumb",
     $j(this).parent('div')
     .next()
     .child('table:first')
     .next()
   );
   thethumb.attr("src", slideSource);
 });
```

Here I use a context to the $j(".slider-thumb", context) selector. The context is a part of the DOM where you're sure the only image with class "slider-thumb' is your target.

Comment: Could I give each post a simple number rel? So post one would be rel=1 and so on? How could we implement that?

Comment: the collest thing would be to add a unique "id" id attrubute to each post and the same id with '-slider' for slider images, then you just need to extract the id from slider image, remove '-slider' and then you can select you thumb by id $("#"+myid). If you cannot play with th id the goal would be adding attribute rel="the-corresponding-thumb-id" on the slide-image. Then you extract it with $(this).attr(rel). But I'm not sure I completly understand your needs :-)